# Why not classmethod in this line?

Tags: python, static-methods, class-method

I read [this method](https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers/blob/b0ee27847ffefef7de89b9f69ff5244cb0be6428/bindings/python/py_src/tokenizers/implementations/bert_wordpiece.py#L83) in a repository by huggingface:

```
@staticmethod
def from_file(vocab: str, **kwargs):
    vocab = WordPiece.read_file(vocab)
    return BertWordPieceTokenizer(vocab, **kwargs)
```

It returns an instantiation of a class, then I wonder why not classmethod?

Comment: Maybe you should attempt to answer your own question first. Why would you even think that this method should be a `@classmethod`?

Comment: A `@classmethod` receives an additional parameter to let it know which subclass it was invoked on, and would typically use that parameter to create an instance of that particular subclass.  For a method that creates an instance of some hard-coded class, making it a classmethod would be pointless.

Comment: `It returns an instantiation of a class` That's not what makes a classmethod...

Comment: @JohnGordon What about e.g. [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys)?

Comment: @ekhumoro I don't understand.  Sure, a classmethod _can_ return a class instance, but that does not _make_ it a classmethod, which the questioner seemed to think was the case.

Comment: @JohnGordon It could also be interpreted as a question about the *design* of the method. It seems natural to ask why the author of the code chose to do things that way. Is there some specific reason why the method hard-codes the returned type?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you expect it to be like this:

```py
@classmethod
def from_file(cls, vocab: str, **kwargs):
    vocab = WordPiece.read_file(vocab)
    return cls(vocab, **kwargs)
```

The problem with this is that for each inheriting class it will use that class to instantiate an object rather than `BertWordPieceTokenizer`. I would think they don't want that to be the case, because it will be error-prone and easily break things on child classes.

Comment: Surely it's much more unintuitive and error-prone for it *not* to return an of object of the same class? I would expect it to be *way* more common for `from*` methods to always preserve type. That's how e.g. `dict.fromkeys` behaves, and the same goes for many of the classes found in stdlib modules (e.g. `datetime`, `fractions`, `collections`, etc). For the rare occasions when the type has to be hard-coded, a module-level function should always be preferred. Using a `staticmethod` in those situations just invites confusion.

Comment: Yes, I expect it to be that. I cannot find any benefits of the hard coded instantiation in that huggingface scenario.

Comment: @LernerZhang I think the author probably just didn't consider subclassing, so it's a design bug in their implementation.